# How to aggregate ilike found search on multiple row in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, search, query-optimization

Let say I have this table

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE pizzas (
  pizza_id             INT,
  name                 TEXT,
  ingredients          TEXT,
  kingsize_ingredients TEXT
);
```

and some entries

```
pizza_id |      name       |       ingredients           |         kingsize_ingredients
---------+-----------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------
    1    |  moutainview    | cheese,sausage,potato       | cheese,sausage,potato,tomato
    2    |  the o' chicken | cheese,chicken,tomato       | cheese,chicken,tomato,eggs
    3    |  hawai          | mozarella,tomato,pineapple  | mozarella,tomato,pineapple,sausage
```

This is fictive, in this example I stack ingredients in a long comma separated string, I know it is stupid but I try to provide an environment for my question.

So basically, the dummy engine takes a string and search for matches in the `pizzas` table. The search is performed on multiple columns and **my goal** is to make a search engine that will not only return the name of the pizzas where the search matches but also return the columns in the row where the search did match.

So for instance if I search *"tomato"* in the previous table, I should have this output :

```
 name           |         found_in
----------------+-------------------------------------
 mountainview   | {kingsize_ingredients}
 hawai          | {ingredients,kingsize_ingredients}
 the o' chicken | {ingredients,kingsize_ingredients}
```

Actually I sort of answered my question and here I provide the solution :

```
SELECT
  name,
  array_agg(found_in) AS found_in
FROM (
       SELECT
         *,
         'ingredients' AS found_in
       FROM pizzas
       WHERE ingredients ILIKE '%tomato%'

       UNION ALL

       SELECT
         *,
         'kingsize_ingredients' AS found_in
       FROM pizzas
       WHERE kingsize_ingredients ILIKE '%tomato%'
     ) AS founds
GROUP BY (name)
```

But I think when it comes to search, optimisation is a priority and because I made this query with my personal knowledge about PostgreSQL (which is not my field of expertise) I am not sure if I am doing that right. This question is not about debating what is the way of making this PostgreSQL query as optimized as possible, it's about asking if this query is having a bad structure or flaws ?

Here is the code if need to initialize at home :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pizzas;
CREATE TEMP TABLE pizzas (
  pizza_id             INT,
  name                 TEXT,
  ingredients          TEXT,
  kingsize_ingredients TEXT
);

INSERT INTO pizzas VALUES
  (1, 'moutainview', 'cheese,sausage,potato', 'cheese,sausage,potato,tomato'),
  (2, 'the o'' chicken', 'cheese,chicken,tomato', 'cheese,chicken,tomato,eggs'),
  (3, 'hawai', 'mozarella,tomato,pineapple', 'mozarella,tomato,pineapple,sausage');
```

Thanks

Comment: Your current query actually looks pretty good, at least given the constraints of your problem.  Break those CSV values over separate rows and the problem gets much simpler though.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah I know this is bad data structure, actually I am making a simple search engine for a local library and the columns are not CSV. Just to imply occurrences.

Comment: You might want to look into using full text search with Postgres.

Comment: I would use `string_agg()` instead of `array_agg()` but apart from that I agree with Tim

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for the reference, I was looking for that kind of tool.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name good, I've replaced with `string_agg`, it looks better and the back-end appreciates it also. thanks